# How to compile Ruby c extension on Ruby 2.2.1 for sketchup plugin?

Tags: sketchup, ruby-c-extension

I have used a Ruby C Extension for SketchUp Plugin. Ruby version is `1.9.3` and SketchUp2016. But I have to recompile the Ruby C extension to upgrade the plugin package that supports ruby version of `2.2.1` P85.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the version of Ruby that SketchUp uses. SketchUp 13 and older used Ruby 1.8, while SketchUp 2014 up til the current SketchUp 2016 uses Ruby 2.0.

You cannot compile against Ruby 1.9, or 2.2 or any other flavor if you plan on loading the C Extension in SketchUp.

The SketchUp github account contain libs and headers that match the shipped Ruby versions of SketchUp: https://github.com/SketchUp/ruby-c-extension-examples